# What is different meaning of source and code in programming?

Tags: module, definition

Excerpt From: Robert C. Martin. “Clean Architecture: A Craftsman's Guide to Software Structure and Design (Robert C. Martin Series).”

> “Now, what do we mean by the word “module”? The simplest definition is just a source file. Most of the time that definition works fine. Some languages and development environments, though, don’t use source files to contain their code. In those cases a module is just a cohesive set of functions and data structures.”

I got confused about "source" and "code" here. What does him meaning when he wrote "don’t use source files to contain their code"?

Thanks your explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"code" can be any `statement` or `expression`. "Source code" and "code" can be used interchangeably.

A file system file (ie. `helloworld.c`) can contain any number of `statements`. However, some development environments do not use files to store their code. Conceptually it could be just on the web and stored in a database, or the code could be in-memory only, and so not in a file.

In this particular passage, Mr. Martin (also known as Uncle Bob) is trying to illustrate that a `module` can mean different things depending upon the language or development environment. It is better to concentrate on the last line you quoted: `a module is just a cohesive set of functions and data structures.` as this is a sufficient definition without getting confused about the storage location of the code.